# Why do I now need to use WebDriverWait in all my Selenium tests?

Tags: python, selenium

I use Selenium to test the user interface of a web application. These tests have worked consistently for the past year. Now, they are all failing. As I am slowly fixing them, I keep having to use `WebDriverWait` to wait for URLs to load. For example, this test used to pass:

```
def test_alphanumeric_username(self):
    # This function creates a new user by navigating to a new page.
    # On completion, a message should flash on the user's screen.
    register_user(self.browser, username='@@@')
    message = get_flashed_message(self.browser)
    self.assertEqual(message, 'Username must be alphanumeric.')

def get_flashed_message(browser):
    message = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="flashes"]//p')
    return message.text
```

But every test that relied on `get_flashed_message` failed until I made this modification:

```
def get_flashed_message(browser):
    message = wait_until(browser, '//div[@class="flashes"]//p')
    return message.text

def wait_until(browser, xpath_selector, timeout=20):
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)
    return wait.until(lambda b: b.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_selector))
```

This problem is happening with all my tests, and now my code is littered with calls to wait or sleep. What could have changed? Selenium's API? My application? My dev environment?

Comment: It could be anything, but I encounter this kind of problem when I change my test environment (preprod1 to preprod2 for example). I suggest you to include your waiting operation in your basic methods (like "click") so that your code isn't full of "wait.until".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you recently switch to using geckodriver? If so, you could be seeing [this issue](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/308)

If not, did the way the flashes are presented change on the web application? e.g. they used to be presented upon page load and now they load via javascript asynchronously

Comment: The switch to Selenium 3 / geckodriver was the issue.